# How to merge a big number of JPEG pictures to a filename-labelled merged PDF file in OS X?

Tags: photos, pdf, preview, graphics

I have a large number of JPEG files. Each JPEG file has a name in the format **nameX.jpeg**.

I want to merge them to PDF such that one JPEG picture is on one PDF page where the name of JPEG is a label on each new PDF page. This will result into a merged PDF with each JPEG picture on separate page.

**How can I combine JPEG picture files to labelled PDF file in OS X?**

Answer (score -1):

There are programming approaches with ImageMagic and Python's img2pdf where you have to install brew to OS X.

**ImageMagick**

```
$ brew install imagemagick

$ convert 'FILENAME.JPG'  -background Khaki  -pointsize 40 -size 40x label:'FILENAME.jpg'      -gravity Center -append 'OUTPUT.JPG'  
$ ...do this for each file...
```

Loop this script with Automator or some other OS X tool.

Comment: How does this create a PDF?